# Performance of ArrayBlockingQueue and SubmissionPublisher

Tags: java, performance, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I have written performance tests of single producer single consumer scenario against `ArrayBlockingQueue` and `SubmissionPublisher`. I am surprised that `SubmissionPublisher` performs far better than `ArrayBlockingQueue` (or my tests are wrong).

Both use array as the buffer, so why is the result so different?

```java
Benchmark                                 Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
ArrayBlockingQueuePerfTest.runBenchmark     ss    5  16.772 ± 0.538   s/op
SubmissionPublisherPerfTest.runBenchmark    ss    5   8.138 ± 0.061   s/op
```

Test for `ArrayBlockingQueue`

```java
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class ArrayBlockingQueuePerfTest {

    private BlockingQueue<Event> queue;
    private CountDownLatch latch;
    private ExecutorService executor;
    private TestRunnable testRunnable;
    private Future<?> future;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        org.openjdk.jmh.Main.main(new String[] { ArrayBlockingQueuePerfTest.class.getCanonicalName() });
    }

    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.SingleShotTime)
    @Fork(value = 1)
    @Warmup(iterations = 5)
    @Measurement(iterations = 5)
    public void runBenchmark() throws Exception {
        for (int i=0; i<100_000_000; ++i) {
            queue.put(new Event(i));
        }
        latch.await();
    }

    @Setup(Level.Trial)
    public void setupAll() {
        queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(16384);
        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        testRunnable = new TestRunnable(queue);
        future = executor.submit(testRunnable);
    }

    @Setup(Level.Iteration)
    public void setup() {
        latch = new CountDownLatch(100_000_000);
        testRunnable.reset(latch);
    }

    @TearDown(Level.Trial)
    public void tearDown() {
        future.cancel(true);
        executor.shutdown();
    }

    static class TestRunnable implements Runnable {

        private final BlockingQueue<Event> queue;
        private CountDownLatch latch;

        public TestRunnable(BlockingQueue<Event> queue) {
            this.queue = queue;
        }

        public void reset(CountDownLatch latch) {
            this.latch = latch;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    queue.take();
                    latch.countDown();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Test for `SubmissionPublisher`

```java
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class SubmissionPublisherPerfTest {

    private ExecutorService executor;
    private SubmissionPublisher<Event> publisher;
    private TestSubscriber subscriber;
    private CountDownLatch latch;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        org.openjdk.jmh.Main.main(new String[] { SubmissionPublisherPerfTest.class.getCanonicalName() });
    }

    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.SingleShotTime)
    @Fork(value = 1)
    @Warmup(iterations = 5)
    @Measurement(iterations = 5)
    public void runBenchmark() throws Exception {
        for (int i=0; i<100_000_000; ++i) {
            publisher.submit(new Event(i));
        }
        latch.await();
    }

    @Setup(Level.Trial)
    public void setupAll() {
        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        publisher = new SubmissionPublisher<>(executor, 16384);
        subscriber = new TestSubscriber();
        publisher.subscribe(subscriber);
    }

    @Setup(Level.Iteration)
    public void setup() {
        latch = new CountDownLatch(100_000_000);
        subscriber.reset(latch);
    }

    @TearDown(Level.Trial)
    public void tearDownAll() {
        executor.shutdown();
    }

    static class TestSubscriber implements Flow.Subscriber<Event> {

        private CountDownLatch latch;
        private Flow.Subscription subscription;

        public void reset(CountDownLatch latch) {
            this.latch = latch;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Flow.Subscription subscription) {
            (this.subscription = subscription).request(1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Event item) {
            this.subscription.request(1);
            latch.countDown();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable throwable) {}

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {}
    }
}
```

The `Event` object

```
public class Event {
    private int value;

    public Event() {
    }

    public Event(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```